# Getting frame of subview enumeration

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame, subview

So, I have repeating views containing thumbnails, once a thumbnail is pressed the thumbnail ID is sent as the tag.

With this information I want to get the frame of the subview of that view;

```
- (IBAction)thumbPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Thumb %i pressed", (int)[sender tag]);

    for (int i = 0; i < _thumbCounter; i++) {
        if (i == [sender tag]) {
            NSLog(@"thumb view %i", i);

            //Up To HERE

            break;
        }
    }

//    [self moveToVideoControllerWithInfoID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)[sender tag]]];
}
```

For the thumbnails to be drawn they're drawn in a random order retrieved by JSON.

The Button

```
UIButton *thumbButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[thumbButton addTarget:self
           action:@selector(thumbPressed:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
thumbButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _thumbView.frame.size.width, _thumbView.frame.size.height);
thumbButton.tag = _thumbCounter;
[_thumbView addSubview:thumbButton];
```

The subview I want to get the frame of

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"***.jpg",Link];

NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(thumbGap, thumbGap, thumbHeight - 5, thumbHeight - 5)];
imageView.image = image;

[_thumbView addSubview:imageView];
```

Where the thumbnail shell is drawn

```
_thumbView = [[ThumbView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, margin, _scrollView.frame.size.width, thumbHeight)];
_thumbView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_thumbView.thumbId = _thumbCounter;
[_scrollView addSubview:_thumbView];
```

_thumbview is a class of UIVIEW with the added thumbId

How once that button is pressed can I locate the imageView frame inside of _thumbview ( bare in mind there are multiple ).

Comment: I'm just trying to determine your logic. It would be easier if you could draw this as a tree diagram in <ul><<li></li>/ul> format, could you help by doing that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let's make life easier for you:

```
- (IBAction)thumbPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSLog(@"Thumb %i pressed", (int)[sender tag]);
    ThumbView *thumbView = (ThumbView*)[sender superView];
    for(UIView* subview in thumbView.subViews) {
        if([subView iKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            //you got it here
        }
    }
}
```

You could shortcut the whole thing by making ThumbView have an imageView property as well.

I've tried to determine that this is what you are doing:

```
_scrollView
->_thumbView[0]
--->thumbButton
--->imageView
->_thumbView[1]
--->thumbButton
--->imageView
...
->_thumbView[N]
--->thumbButton
--->imageView
```

Assumed that you want the image view who is in the same thumbView as the button who is pressed.

Best Possible Solution (IMHO):

```
@Interface ThumbView()
    @property (nonatomic,weak) UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

AND:
(After making sure to first add, and THEN SET .imageView)

```
- (IBAction)thumbPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSLog(@"Thumb %i pressed", (int)[sender tag]);
    UIImageView *imageView = ((ThumbView*)[sender superView]).imageView
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I sort of came to the same conclusion with a bit more finger effort I'll accept your answer and post my own .

Comment: Even better, you're a very smart guy. I appreciate the extra effort !

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *i in _scrollView.subviews) {
    if ([i isKindOfClass:[ThumbView class]]) {
        ThumbView *tempThumb = (ThumbView *)i;
        if (tempThumb.thumbId == (int)[sender tag]) {
            for (UIView *y in tempThumb.subviews) {
                if ([y isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                    UIImageView *tempIMG = (UIImageView *)y;

                    [self playVideo:[loadedInput objectForKey:@"link"] frame:tempIMG.frame andView:tempThumb];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While it's a good effort, I do believe it could be done with a little less extreme depth of nesting. Your best friend is the fact that the view in question is already passed, UIButton*

Comment: I'm not trying to criticise, but just take it from someone who reviews and maintains code constantly, you will thank yourself in the future if you use less deep nesting, trust me :)

Comment: @MitchellCurrie due to my lack of experience in views ( used to sprite kit ) I'm lacking easier terms. Thanks for assisting me shorten my code !

Comment: Happy to help. Please check the bottom of the revised solution for what i consider most elegant.